# how to instantiate a viewmodel using VML SimpleIoc?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, mvvm, ioc-container, mvvm-light

So basically I need to instantiate a viewmodel directly from another viewmodel , I'm using MVVMLight, people say I can do that using the MVVMLight ViewModelLocator , I tried this line of code on my source ViewModel A, to instantiate destination ViewModel B

```
SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<BViewModel>();
```

didn't work , any ideas ?

Comment: This should work. GetInstance returns the default instance of BViewModel, which is instantiated on demand if needed. Place a breakpoint in BViewModel constructor, I suspect something goes wrong when the IOC container try to instantiate it.

Comment: my fault , it works just fine , I just forget the simple fact that now my VM will load twice, and I had an error on the constructor so that I've never received the second call(the view call) and I was assuming all the time that this one call I have is the second call and the first call(VM call) never occured, I fixed the error on the constructor and now I have two calls

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you need to use your code in the constructor of View B like this:

```
this.DataContext = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<BViewModel>();
```

This way your View is coupled with an Instance of your BViewModel, in your example you're just Instantiating it.

You can find more info about constructing ViewModels and Views here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec17

But I do have some experience with WP7 programming and recommend using your IOC Container from the constructor of your View. This because the parameters you are passing will be pushed into your View using the standard Navigational Methods of your WP7 Page.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but for this to work ,View B has to run first and thats exactly what I want to avoid, in simple words, I need to instantiate View B ViewModel from View A ViewModel

Comment: In that case you should use a DataTemplate, this does exactly what you want. On the same page 3 headers down: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg405484(v=pandp.40).aspx#sec20

Comment: Maybe an even better example of what you're looking for:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090097

Comment: I appreciate your effort , but I read Josh article on MVVM long time ago , and I practice MVVM since then ,I will edit the question to be more specific